# Comparing a string of 6 digits to 6 char variables using NO methods from the string class

Tags: java, string, char, match, bufferedreader

"You are not allowed to use any methods from the String class for finding matches. You may and should use the isDigit() method. The isDigit() method is a static method in the Character class. Failure to observe this constraint will result in a significant loss of points."

Currently I'm cheating by using:

```
        System.out.println("Please enter your birthday in the format MMDDYY: ");

            bday = reader.readLine();
            char[] cArr = bday.toCharArray();
            [...]
            while (br.ready()) {
            //compare to bday
            comp++;
            if (cArr[0] == one && cArr[1] == two && cArr[2] == three && cArr[3] == four && cArr[4] == five && cArr[5] == six) {
                System.out.println("Your birthday " + bday + " was found at character position " + pos + " in piDigits.txt");
                System.out.println("The number of comparisons so far is: " + comp);
            }
            //move chars around. Any time the first char changes, add one to position to keep track of the digit the match starts on
            one = two;
            pos++;
            two = three;
            three = four;
            four = five;
            five = six;

            //assign new char to the end of the list
            six = (char) br.read();
            while (!Character.isDigit(six) && br.ready()) {
                six = (char) br.read();
            }
```

My problem here is that bday.toCharArray is a method of the string class.

Comment: It says "You are not allowed to use any methods from the String class for finding matches." But here you are just using it to convert String to Char Array. Also, as written, `isDigit()` is static method for `char` and not for `String`. :)

Comment: I think the instructions need to be interpreted as barring you from using any of the _matching_ methods from the `String` class. Otherwise, the assignment is impossible, since method calls are the _only_ way to access individual characters of a `String`. Check with your teacher or TA. (By the way, what is `br`?

Comment: It doesn't say "NO methods", it says "[no methods] for **finding matches**", which means you can't use `indexOf()`, but `toCharArray()` and `charAt()` are ok.

Comment: feels weird helping you cheat on your homework ;) how about instead of reading the line as a string, read it character by character? that way you don't have to use the toCharArray() ?

Comment: I figured I'd make an account on stakeoverflow to ask just in case I was missing something about strings and chars. I know I /should/ be able to use it like user2004685 said... but this is also the professor who tried to make a joke out of me in front of our class because "why would you need a 4 digit year? 1904, 2004, 2104, etc are all leap years!" Spoiler alert, 1900 is not, even though 2000 is. 4 digit years please.

Comment: If the rule is as draconian as you think, there is always the `.read()` method of reader.

Answer (score 0):

Well I thought this was an interesting thing to play with and came up with this solution.  Based on the question and time of year it doesn't seem like they would've covered what I have here so it helps you but it doesn't help you :)

```
    char c; 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));       
    List<Character> inputBirthday = new ArrayList<Character>();
    List<Character> knownBirthday = new ArrayList<Character>();
    boolean inputMatchesBirthday = false;

    knownBirthday.add('1');
    knownBirthday.add('2');
    knownBirthday.add('2');
    knownBirthday.add('5');
    knownBirthday.add('0');
    knownBirthday.add('0');

    System.out.println("Enter birthdate MMDDYY.");      
    do{ 
        c = (char) br.read(); 
        if(!Character.isSpace(c)){
            inputBirthday.add(c);
        }
    } while(Character.isDigit(c)); 


    if(inputBirthday.size() != knownBirthday.size()){
        inputMatchesBirthday = false;
    }else{
        for(int i = 0; i < knownBirthday.size(); i ++){
            if(knownBirthday.get(i) != inputBirthday.get(i)){
                inputMatchesBirthday = false;
                break;
            }
            inputMatchesBirthday = true;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Do they match?: " + (inputMatchesBirthday == true ? "yes" : "no") );
```

Comment: Since the instructions you shared didn't specify much, I made the assumption that you had a predetermined date to compare the input to